# Access intent used to launch activity in a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent

I have an activity `LauncherActivity.java` that is launched using an intent. This intent contains extras. `LauncherActivity.java` analyses this extra and launches one of multiple fragments.
The scenario is something like this :

> `LauncherActicity` has multiple fragments which act as pages. Now,
>   from one of these pages I launch a foreign activity. Now pressing back
>   would ideally bring me back to my fragment in `LauncherActicity` but
>   in an event where `LauncherActicity` is killed in the background, the
>   back button would not be enough. To prevent that, always using an
>   intent to get back to `LauncherActicity` would ensure the flow is
>   unaffected even when `LauncherActicity` is killed in the background.

My requirement is, I want to access this intent in the fragment that is launched so that I can extract more information that is also present in the intent's extras.

The problem is when I do this using `getActivity().getIntent()`, the intent does not have any extras and even the action is null.
How can I preserve this intent so that any of the fragments can access it using `getActivity().getIntent()`?

My code does not allow me to pass all of this data in constructor or write the data to some global variables.

**EDIT**
I tested the above with the following steps :

1. When in foreign activity, I force stopped the the process in which `LauncherActivity` resides and then fired the intent for `LauncherActivity`.
2. `LauncherActivity` showed up as expected and so did the fragment.
3. This time, when I accessed the intent from the fragment using `getActivity().getIntent()`, the intent and all the extras in it were available in the fragment.

**OBSERVATION**

It seems when the `LauncherActivity`'s application is already present in the backstack, the intent for this activity invokes `onNewIntent()` whereas when the application is killed in the background, the intent invokes activity's `onCreate()`.
Fragment is able to only access the intent using `getActivity().getIntent()` that was used to create the activity (i.e, the intent that invoked `onCreate()`). The rest of the intents are not accessible to the fragment.
Since the application containing `LauncherActivity` is initially launched without intent, in a happy case, all the foreign intents will be invoking `onNewIntent()` and won't be accessible in the fragment.

Comment: If your current flow is `IntentX -> LauncherActivity -> Fragment`, why don't you make it so the Fragments are shown in the Activity that holds `IntentX`? It should look like this: `ActivityX -> Fragment`.

Comment: The intent is triggered from a foreign activity and received in the `LauncherActivity`. This `LauncherActivity` holds the fragment. I verified this by printing the parent activity using `getActivity().getClass().getName()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I didn't make my question clear enough initially but I was surprised I didn't receive this answer : 
A `Fragment` residing inside an `Activity`, when calls `getActivity()`, will receive a reference for this `Activity`. Which means calling `getActivity().getIntent()` will return the intent that was used to **create** this `Activity`. If the `Activity` receives an intent that while it is already running in backstack, the intent will be just another intent.
These 2 different kind of intents are treated differently :

1. Intent that is used to create the `Activity` will invoke it's `onCreate()`.
2. Intent that is used to invoke `Activity` that is already running, will invoke 
   it's `onNewIntent()`.

`Activity` will only maintain the intent that invokes it's `onCreate()` and the intent that invokes it's `onNewIntent()` is destroyed after the scope of this function runs out. Hence, to maintain the intent that is received in `onNewIntent()` we need to explicitly override the previous intent that invoked `Activity`'s `onCreate()` with this new intent using :

> `setIntent(intent)`.

Answer (score 0):

This breaks the isolation of the fragment from the activity.

If you instanciate your fragment programmatically when receiving the intent, you can always pass the data to the fragment via its bundle.

Else, you could:

- use a **callback** as shown in https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#EventCallbacks in a twisted way to have your activity expose the data
- better (in my opinion), use a **ViewModel** shared between your activity and your fragment, as described in https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing

Comment: I have updated by question to indicate the whole picture. The purpose of the intent is to resume the fragment even if the `LauncherActicity` is killed.